# Can the bash "autocomplete" (via TAB TAB) entries be colored/formated?

Tags: bash

**Background:**

The "autocomplete" feature I am talking about is when you half-type a command or filename in bash, if you press TAB twice it will print out suggestions.

**Question:**

The entries output looks allot like the default `ls` behavior.

How could I override this to give it different colors or format (like `ls`)?

**EDIT: Copy paste of [Answer on UnixStackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/is-there-a-way-to-set-coloring-for-cd-tab-complete/133866#133866) - vote for it there!**

In bash 4.3 and later you can add

```
set colored-stats on
```

to `~/.inputrc`.

See http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html:

> `colored-stats`
>
> If set to ``on`', Readline displays possible completions using different colors to indicate their file type. The color definitions are taken from the value of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable. The default is ``off`'.

You can use http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/ to generate both `LS_COLORS` (which is used by GNU `ls` and `colored-stats`) and `LSCOLORS‏` (which is used by BSD `ls`).

Comment: Check this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/133866/45365

Comment: Probably too late, but the question should probably be migrated so that it can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Append ***set colored-stats on*** to your input-rc file.

```
[[ -f $INPUTRC ]] && echo set colored-stats on >> $INPUTRC
```

Or if you have it in the default location:

```
echo set colored-stats on >> ~/.inputrc
```

Then restart bash.

That's it.

[image: colored completions]